# What are the best Cache practices in ehcache or spring cache for spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache, spring-cache

Planning to implement cache mechanism for static data in spring web based application, can any one explain which is the best and how it works?

- EhCache
- Spring Cache

Comment: You want a comparison between ehcache and spring cache ?

Comment: No I would like to know how these two support, or i need to use both to achieve cache?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*Disclaimer : I am a [Terracotta / Software AG](http://www.terracotta.org) employee, the maintainers of Ehcache*

[Ehcache](http://ehcache.org) is a JVM caching library, famous for being used as the default 2nd level cache for the Hibernate ORM

[Spring cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache) was introduced in Spring 3.1, and brought annotations such as `@CachePut` to define uses of caches in a Spring application; by default Spring cache uses a plain Map, but you can configure it to use any popular caching framework, including Ehcache

Since Spring 4.1, Spring cache supports [JSR-107](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107), the standard for caching on the JVM.

What that means, is that you can add JSR-107 caching annotations, and then choose your caching library ([ehcache 2 or 3](http://www.ehcache.org/) / [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) / [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) / [etc.](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/implementations/jsr107/index.html)) : you're not tied to any caching vendor, even not tied to Spring cache annotations !

There's [this nice blog post explaining the parallel between Spring cache annotations and JSR-107 annotations](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/14/cache-abstraction-jcache-jsr-107-annotations-support) and if you choose to use Ehcache3 in your spring boot application, [there's another interesting blog post explaining you how to integrate it in your app](http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2016/05/18/ehcache3_jsr107_spring.html)

Comment: One quirk with the JSR annotations is that there isn't protection from the thundering herd problem. That functionality requires using a loader so that the CacheResult method body isn't invoked. It gets really ugly.

Comment: Thanks Lot Anthony, My doubt is that Do i need to user en-cache and spring cache ?

Comment: @DelliKilari, I suggest you enable Spring cache in your application, use Jcache  / jsr107 annotations in your code and configure ehcache3 or any other jsr107 implementations as your caching implementation (see the links in my answer)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answering my doubts.

Comment: @AnthonyDahanne : Can you please give the best and quick ehcache.xml default cache configurations when implementing ehcache with hibernate 2nd level cache?

Comment: @Jajikanth : have a look at : https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/xmlconfig/fullstack/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml

Comment: I see it's an 3 years old answer but on ehcache site and [example code](https://github.com/gibsong/ehcache-jsr107-spring/tree/master/src/main/resources) there is still `ehcache.xml`. Is it possible to totally get rid off xml file and do only java configuration for ehcache 3.8 and spring boot 2.1 (or above)?

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache3 has support for JSR 107

For Ehcache2 may be you can use this implementation

https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache-jcache/tree/master/ehcache-jcache