# EhCache 3 and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, ehcache-3, cachemanager

Is there a way to abstract the EhCache 3 CacheManager (`org.ehcache.CacheManager`) to Spring's CacheManager (`org.springframework.cache.CacheManager`)?

With EhCache2, it is possible, by the following:

```
  @Bean
  public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager(net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehcache) {    
    EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager(ehcache);
    return cacheManager;
  }
```

HINT: I've found a way to abstract the `javax.cache.CacheManager` cacheManager to the Spring's CacheManager (`org.springframework.cache.CacheManager`), by:

```
  @Bean
  public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager(javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
  }
```

It will be also helpful if there is a way to cast `org.ehcache.CacheManager` to `javax.cache.CacheManager` .

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should rely on the standard Java caching specification, JSR-107, aka JCache (javax.cache.CacheManager)

Spring has a nice integration of it, and Ehcache2 and Ehcache3 also are compatible with it

Please have a look at this answer, it also comes with some simple examples : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39340151/24069